# Android: "The id is not defined anywhere" but it clearly is

Tags: android

I am getting this error for referring this line 
`android:layout_below="@id/nav_drawer_header_include"` I don't understand how this could even be, wen android itself auto completed me with the id name.

This is the complete layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <include layout="@layout/nav_header_main"
                     android:id="nav_drawer_header_include"/>

            <ListView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/nav_drawer_header_include">



            </ListView>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
android:id="@+id/nav_drawer_header_include"
```

Instead of this

```
android:id="nav_drawer_header_include"
```

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
<include layout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    android:id="@+id/nav_drawer_header_include"/>

<ListView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/nav_drawer_header_include">
```